# How to convert a passing string paramatre to int on asp.net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

i'm a Asp.net MVC Develpoer and i have problem with converting string to int because i
because i nedd it on search. When i tryed to write this code on the Contoller:

```
public ViewResult Search(string textboxmvc)
{
    var student = from i in db.StudentSet  select i;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxmvc))
    {
        student = student.Where(s => s.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())
                                   || s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())||s.Id==int.Parse(textboxmvc));

    }

     return View(student);

}
```

it shows this problem:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Source Error:


Line 42:                     </tr>
Line 43: 
Line 44:                 <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
Line 45:                     <tr>
Line 46:                    


Source File: d:\aimen\Projects\Schoo_Project\Schoo_Project\Views\Students\Search.aspx    Line: 44
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to parse it beforehand.

```
public ViewResult Search(string textboxmvc)
{
    int parsedId;
    int.TryParse(textboxmvc, out parsedId);
    var student = from i in db.StudentSet  select i;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxmvc))
    {
        student = student.Where(s => s.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())
                                   || s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())||s.Id==parsedId);

    }

     return View(student);

}
```

Comment: +1 for `int.TryParse`, since it appears same `textboxmvc` is used for getting name as well as ID

Answer (score 1):

Assign it to another variable first.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxmvc))
{
    var textboxmvcAsInt = int.Parse(textboxmvc);
    student = student.Where(s => s.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())
                               || s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())||s.Id==textboxmvcAsInt);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ViewResult Search(string textboxmvc)
{
    var student = from i in db.StudentSet  select i;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxmvc))
    {
        int val = int.Parse(textboxmvc);
        student = student.Where(s => s.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())
                                   || s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())||s.Id==val);

    }

     return View(student);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the conversion outside of the LINQ expression:

```
var numericValue = int.Parse(textboxmvc);

student = student.Where(s => s.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())
                           || s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())||s.Id==numericValue);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pares textbox content to `int` outside LINQ to Entities query:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxmvc))
{
    var id = int.Parse(textboxmvc)
    student = student.Where(s => s.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())
                               || s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())
                               || s.Id == id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ doesn't know how to convert `Int.Parse` to SQL code.  Do the cast and assign it to a variable before the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxmvc))
 {
    int i = int.Parse(textboxmvc);
    student = student.Where(s => s.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())     
                 ||    s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())||s.Id==i);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to make the conversion before `Where` like this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxmvc))
    {
        var number = int.Parse(textboxmvc);
        student = student.Where(s => s.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())
                                   || s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(textboxmvc.ToUpper())||s.Id==number);

    }
```